# VBA coed mandatory fields based off of specific data

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form using Excel in column A11 I have a dropdown box with three options.  If one of these options are selected the entire row is required.  I have searched everywhere and cant find the right code. I am new to using VBA

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

     Dim rsave As Range
     Dim cell As Range

     Set rsave = Sheet1.Range("B11)]")

     For Each cell In rsave

          If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

          Dim missdata
          missdata = MsgBox("Missing Data - Enter the Date for WorkBook to Save", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data")
          Cancel = True
          cell.Offset(0, 1).Select

      Exit For

      End If

      Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: If the value in column A is not empty or "SELECT ONE", before the workbook is closed, it should generate a pop-up if one of column B:I is not populated, correct?

Comment: correct Rik, with the exception of Select One, I have a ADD, Delete, and other in the drop downbox

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Set "SheetToCheck" to the sheet you wish to Check.
It will stop looping as soon as it has found a missing value and the MsgBox will give the 1st Range where it found a missing value.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim CellToCheck As Range
    Dim exitLoops As Boolean
    Set ws = Worksheets("SheetToCheck")

    lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    exitLoops = False

    With ws
        'Loop over rows:
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If exitLoops = True Then Exit For

            If .Range("A" & i).value <> "" And .Range("A" & i).value <> "SELECT ONE" Then

                'Loop over cells in row:
                For Each CellToCheck In .Range("B" & i & ":K" & i)
                    If exitLoops = True Then Exit For
                    If CellToCheck.value = "" Then
                        Cancel = True
                        MsgBox "Missing Data in cell " & CellToCheck.Address
                        exitLoops = True
                    End If
                Next CellToCheck
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the information, I added the code. I am a newcomer to VBA, that I did was right click on the sheet, view code, paste the code, I changed "SheetToCheck" to "Sheet1", did I follow the correct procedures. Nothing is happening when I attempt to save????

Comment: You should open the visual basic editor (ALT+F11), double click on "ThisWorkbook" and paste the code there.

Comment: Rik, I am did ALT+F11, the window opened but I don't see anything with "ThisWorkbook" to double click on?     I do see a dropdown for this worksheet.

Comment: eureka i found it, THANKS RIK

Comment: Rik Sportel The code is working, with the exception of : I entered the required fields but the missing data popup will not allow me to save.

Comment: How did you alter it? The reference in  `For Each CellToCheck In .Range("B" & i & ":I" & i)` will basically say "B2:I2" - If you need column L instead of I change it to `...& ":L" & i)` You might actually be validating cells you do not wish to validate - if column i doesn't require values and it's up to H, then change that i to H.

Comment: Rik the only modification I made was the sheet information. I was looking in my book for setting ranges (the cell range I need is B11:K11) and so on B12:K12 etc..

Comment: See edited answer. It will now check each row, each cell column B to K.

Comment: will merged cells cause a problem I am getting "missing data in cell$D$2)

Comment: Merged cells are the work of satan. Yes, they can cause problems.

Comment: LOL, I am unmerging the cells to see if the problem persist, (still not working) how can I skip the cell that are merged which are  C,D,E,F (columns)  from my initial post snapshot of my form which are "To Termini From"  I rather skip those columns

Comment: Just check each cell in `Range("B" & i & ",G" & i & ":K" & i)` (So columns B and G until K) - Please read up on cell referencing in VBA, since these are already different questions.